# android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity vs android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

It seems like a very common issue. I'm trying to import and run an Android app in latest **Eclipse** (neon), but I get the common error of `The import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be resolved`. I've downloaded the library project `android-support-v7-appcompat` from somewhere, and linked it to the project properties. But the errors still here. I see v4 `ActivityCompat` is not throwing any errors, but the v7 **`AppCompatActivity`** shows error, which seems strange. How should I fix it? I am using **Android API 23**.

I already have the support libraries of SDK installed. But when I add the `.jar` libraries (which are just two, one for source, one for javadoc), still nothing happens.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; --> This is ok
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; --> This shows error!
```

[image]

Comment: Prevent headaches, use android studio ;)

Comment: " I've downloaded the library project android-support-v7-appcompat from somewhere." Where is somewhere? If you just downloaded a random library you found on the internet, it is likely out of date. What version of the library do you have?

Comment: @TimCastelijns No the exact problem is not duplicate or at least I couldn't find. I mentioned in the beginning that generally it is a common problem.

Comment: Honestly just use android studio if you can. Android stopped supported eclipse like 18 months ago

Comment: @Tanis.7x I found a project on github that was using this. Do they have a version?! How can I see the version?Remember, I'm not talking about the support library which is provided by the SDK.

Comment: @TimCastelijns For me Android Studio is actually a pain! I'm an Eclipse guy for 10 years! Plus, you can easily search for problems and lots of answers around.

Comment: With android studio you wouldn't even have this problem ;-) anyway good luck.

Comment: That is the absolute worst way to get a library, particularly because you don't know what version it is. And yes, you are talking about the support library (just one of many components of the support library). Even if you stay on Eclipse with the deprecated tools, you should at least switch to Gradle for proper dependency management. If you really need the AAR file, you can find it in your SDK directory under `/extras/android/m2repository`.

Comment: I know about the support files there. There are many folders with different versions. I see some .jar files (which I were adding and no chance), as well as others. What are those AAR files? What should I exactly add to my project?

Answer (score 3):

> I see v4 ActivityCompat is not throwing any errors, but the v7 AppCompatActivity shows error, which seems strange.

Not especially. The random files you grabbed from some random place do not have this class, apparently. `AppCompatActivity` was added sometime after `appcompat-v7` was published as a library, as a long-term replacement for the former `ActionBarActivity`. Presumably, the random files you grabbed from some random place pre-date this change.

> How should I fix it?

Switch to an [AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)-aware build system and an IDE that supports it. Then, depend upon the `appcompat-v7` AAR, which is the only way that `appcompat-v7` is being distributed at the present time.

Or, do not use `appcompat-v7` (or pretty much anything else from the Android Support Library, as most, if not all, of the packages are distributed as AARs, not JARs).